# Preview Latex Fragment in org mode : blank square shown

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

I have an org file, where I put a `LaTeX` fragment to be rendered in line with `C-c C-x C-l`. It is a simple formula:

```
\[
 e^{i\pi} = -1
\]
```

I have `MiKTeX` installed, `latex` and `dvi` commands work from command line in Windows without a problem.
I also have AUCTeX and preview of the same file (embedded in `\begin{document}` and stuff) works fine.

I get the following message in the `messages` buffer:

```
Failed to create dvi file from c:/Users/Michele/AppData/Local/Temp/orgtex6380KuB.tex
Creating images for entry...done.  Use `C-c C-c' to remove images.
Cannot find image file `c:/Users/Michele/Documents/ltxpnghome_5e3cd2413a24591c2b9e10c34d704b6effc5776a.png'
```

What to do next?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to change `org-latex-create-formula-image-program` to `imagemagick` instead of `dvipng` but got no luck. However, during my trials I opened the tex editor of `MiKTeX` to do some other, basically unrelated, testing.
While editor and package manager were open, I went to `emacs` and reverted back to `dvipng` and tried again `C-c C-x C-l`. At this point, I got a series of request to install missing packages!!
Guess what? When the requests ended (it was quite a few), everything was working fine and previews are now correctly displayed!

I have tried to trace back the last packages installed, they should be:

```
ulem, marvosym, wasysym, vasy
```

Hope this can help in a similar case.

Comment: Try to compile `c:/Users/Michele/AppData/Local/Temp/orgtex6380KuB.tex` manually.  When you get this error it's typically because some LaTeX package is missing.

Comment: Please move your UPDATE text to an answer and accept that answer as soon as possible. (It is good practice to answer your own question if you found a solution to your problem.) Otherwise the community bot bumps that question again and again to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should add one of the following lines to your `.emacs` file (or `init.el`) :

```
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'imagemagick)
```

or

```
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvipng)
```

More details and further configuration hints available [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html#sec-3).

Comment: thanks, I am aware of that page and scanned it a few times to no avail...I have to try the `imagemagick` approach, as so far I had the variable set to `dvipng`.
Note that I can see `png` in line, and other `latex` command work fine from the shell (windows).

Comment: Under Ubuntu it is working like a charm with any of the two options but leading to a blank square if none of them is activated.  Let's hope that imagemagick will work for you.