# Why won't my Latex render in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

I have Latex code embedded in my org file.

```
*** Equations
\begin{equation}
h(x) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x
\end{equation}
```

When I run `C-c C-x C-l` while my cursor is on the code, I get an empty box rendered on my file. Why is the code not rendering correctly?

EDIT 1: I have dvipng installed, and I have set org-latex-create-formula-image-program to dvipng.

```
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvipng)
```

I am using org mode version 8.2.10.

EDIT 2: I installed imagemagick and set org-latex-create-formula-image-program to it. No luck. When I run `C-c C-x C-l`, the command bar displays two messages in quick succession.

```
Creating image...1
PDF file /tmp/orgtex8421NqG.pdf wasn't produced
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I installed package `texlive-full`. I was missing some latex packages, which led to a white box being rendered instead of the equation.

The update on this question led me to question whether I had all required latex packages: [Preview Latex Fragment in org mode : blank square shown](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18627/preview-latex-fragment-in-org-mode-blank-square-shown)

Sure enough, when I checked my logs in /tmp directory of my system, I was missing package ulem. On Linux Mint, latex package ulem can be installed by installing `texlive-full`.

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `dvipng` or `imagemagick` installed? Depending on the setting of `org-preview-latex-default-process` (in versions of org-mode >= 9.0) or `org-latex-create-formula-image-program` (in earlier versions), you need one or the other (or you could install both).

Comment: Question edited to address this answer.